# Computer fan sound

Tags: windows-7

In my Asus laptop i keep listening fan sound loudly , What is the reason behind it. ?
Laptop is in screensaver mode also at that time i can hear fan sound loudly for some 
time only.
Please help me know the issue

Comment: Change fancy screen saver to blank screen.

Comment: @Aki fancy screensavers are ancient, so don't need much, so that wouldn't be the cause

Comment: put the laptop on a wood or glass or metal surface , not a carpet or bed, and also, see task manager what occupies cpu

Comment: in task manager >>processes there are plenty of exe files so how do I know which 1 to end

Comment: *> put the laptop on a wood or glass or metal surface , not a carpet or bed, and also, see task manager what occupies cpu*   That would actually *increase* sound because hard surfaces will amplify the vibrations whereas soft surfaces will dampen them. Check that the laptop has rubber feet (not that it matters in this case since it has nothing to do with the fan itself; that is due to overheating).

Comment: This could be a [few things](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+fan+noisy). You’ll have to define “loud”. Is it noisy simply because it’s spinning fast, or is it noisy because it’s rattling or grinding?

Comment: its spinning fast at regular intervals

Comment: Since when does this occur? What kind of screen saver do you use?

Comment: @Synetech: I think that what barlop means is that, when you put the laptop on a soft surface, the fan ports tend to get blocked - putting it on a hard surface *may* increase the vibration noise but it ensures that the fan ports are not obscured.

Comment: *> its spinning fast at regular intervals*   That’s normal. When the CPU gets used more, it heats up, so the fan kicks in to cool it down. I suspect that the intervals are not *quite* as regular as you think, unless something is spiking the CPU load at regular intervals.

Comment: I beleive CPU is spiking up even when there is no work done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the Windows tools such as task manager to see what is running - look for applications that are consistantly >5% or so CPU usage, these are the ones causing the fans to come on because the CPU is working hard when you think it shouldn't be.

It is quite common for a browser such as Firefox to have a process that wont end properly, Java and Flash are common culprits. Some of the Apple tools are also sometimes problematic.

Screen savers are notorious CPU hogs and really shouldn't be used. As others have said, just set the PC to go to a blank screen and set the power settings so that the monitor turns off.

Make sure that you are using the proper power profile too. For normal use, the manufacturers recommended power profile will be the right one as it balances things. Otherwise, choose the Windows "Balanced" power profile.

For older laptops, the recommendation to clean out the fan is a good one, they commonly get clogged with fluff and other rubbish which reduces their efficiency.

Comment: "Process Explorer" (available off the Microsoft web site) is better than Task Manager at identifying tasks that consume CPU.  There is a good chance that some background tasks are causing the problem.

Comment: I agree. Here is the link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: ya thats nice , I will be using process explorer to know whci task is making me trouble

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to show CPU and GPU usage. High usage of either will cause heat and fan noise.

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions for your problem:

- Your fan is dusty, clean it
- Ditch your screensaver (as commented above)
- Look for CPU-Hungry tasks
- Keep you laptop cool
- Reduce CPU-Speed while not using the Laptop or set the power managment correctly, so your laptop clocks down your CPU while not using it (this one will have a slight yet positive impact on battery uptime)

Answer (score -1):

Even though the computer is in screensaver mode when the computer is in idle mode which means the computer is just let on due to which it may do different process like real time scanning ....and so on so. Due to this as the CPU usage exceeds a certain limit the fan's speed may increase accordingly and the fan sound as well.